Garage door closing problem
My garage door will not stay closed. It starts to close for 1 second, then reverses back up for 2 seconds then stops. It is not an obstructed beam. There is no obstruction in the door tracks or in the chain drive. If I disconnect the drive to the door (so it is disengaged & can be moved by hand freely) it still does the same thing. I'm thinking it's the motor relay coil gone weak, not keeping the power to the motor. If I hold down the wall switch button it will move until I release the button but still reverses as before.

there are two travel distance adjustment knobs on the site of the unit. adjust the closing distance. also inspect the big springs

Might not be an obstructed beam, but those are classic symptoms of a misaligned beam.

I tried adjustment of the travel distance knobs, but this did not improve anything. I also did adjust the beam aim to no avail. How is it possible to know if the alignment is good enough?
